# Java: Object ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist, edit

I am saving in an arraylist in this way ("name", "surname", "id", "email", "score")

I trying to edit a user in this arraylist by first searching using id and that part i'm ok with it but then I need to keep the same name,surname and email and just change the score.

Can someone help me, thanks.

Comment: Show us what you have already got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all create a class User

```
  class User{
  String name;
  String Email;
  int Score; 
  // bla bla bla
  }
```

store your users objects in a HashMap

```
HashMap<int,User> map=new HashMap<int,User>();
User u1=new User();
map.put(1,u1);
```

and update the object in the map

```
Integer x=3;
if(map.containsKey(x)){
User u=map.get(x);
u.score=0;
map.put(x,u);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you create a new class whch has attributes("name", "surname", "id", "email", "score")
and afterwards you can get the index that you want if(myarr[i].ID == 1234) and then you can update that index or get the items and equal them to new Class object then delete that item in the required index and then put that index new object again?